# Hot reload and debugging breakpoints for dotnet6 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, vscode-debugger

I tried what is described [here](https://kontext.tech/article/972/visual-studio-code-debug-aspnet-application-with-hot-reload) e.g. updating the following to my `launch.json`, and the program runs.

However, my breakpoints empty out and say `No symbols have been loaded for this document` when I hover them.

Any suggestions?

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "debug-hot-reload",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "--project",
                ".",
                "--verbose"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
                "Key": "Value"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution to your issue:
Adding this line of code:  ***`<DebugType>portable</DebugType>`*** to your ***"yourprojectname.csproj"*** file. This should be helpful to your issue.

If this doesn't work, please let me know and let's see what else can we do.